# An apparent closed form for a slightly tweaked Dirichlet L-function. Could it be proven?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series, euler-product

I made a small tweak to the well-known Dirichlet L-function ($p$=prime):

$$L(s, \chi_4) :=\prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-\chi_4(p)} \bigg)=\prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg) =\beta(s)$$

by injecting $i$, so that the period becomes $i$ and $-i$:

$$F(s) := \bigg| \prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-i\cdot\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg)\bigg|$$

Numerically I found explicit expressions for the positive integers involving $\pi^n$, but then also found I could generalise it towards a closed form that seems valid for all real values of $s > \frac12$:

$$F(s) := \bigg| \prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-i\cdot\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg)\bigg| = \sqrt{ \frac {\zeta(4\,s) \, \left(4^s-4^{-s}\right)}{\zeta(2\,s)\,\left(4^s-1\right)}}$$

Is this a known equation and if not, could it be proven?

Comment: Just square to get $\prod_{p\text{ odd}}\frac{p^{2s}}{p^{2s}+1}$, use the identity $\frac{p^q}{p^q+1}=\frac{p^{2q}}{p^{2q}-1}\times\frac {p^q-1}{p^q}$ and take special care of $p=2$.

Comment: Got it and can fully reconcile now. Thanks fedja!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answered in the comments.

Comment: I am good with closing. Answer was embarrassingly simply.